# android ndk data save/load

Tags: file-io, android-ndk, native-activity

I'm working on porting PC OpenGL application onto Android. I've chosen to use that NDK android_native_app_glue framework stuff. As I understood, it would allow to me stay on C++ and write no even single JAVA code line. And it sounded promising.

The first unclear thing to me it data saving/loading. My application's data format is binary and my original PC-related code uses plain "stdio.h" FILE operations: fopen, fread, fwrite, etc to create, write and read from "mygame.bin" file. How do I port it onto Android?

Having googled it, I found that I must store and then use a "java environment" variable:

```
JNIEnv *g_jniEnv = 0;
void android_main(struct android_app* state) {
    g_jniEnv = state->activity->env;
}
```

However, I still do not realize how to use this g_jniEnv to perform file operations.

**Update:**
Okay, I found that in Java, data saving can be performed as follows:

```
String string = "hello world!";
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("mygame.bin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

So my questions is: given a pointer to JNIEnv, how do I rewrite this code fragment in C++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can still use stdio.h in an NDK project. #include and pound away.

The only trick is getting the path to your application's private data folder. It's available as `state->activity->internalDataPath` in `android_main`. Outside of that path, the app has no filesystem rights.

You will probably need your `JNIEnv` eventually one way or another. The entirety of Java API is not mirrored for the native subsystem; so hold on to that `env`. But native file I/O is right there.

Comment: "Outside of that path, the app has no filesystem rights." Not necessarily true - most obviously if the app has external storage permission.

Comment: Saved at the end of a long day by `internalDataPath`. Cheers.